# How to make vertical nav full width on left side with grid bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to create admin panel with bootstrap. First I want to make navigation menu in the left side. I get the problem my navigation in the red background did not full width in the left columns like this code :

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2" style="background-color:#f0f;">
      <div class="nav flex-column" style="background-color:#f00;">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
        </li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-10">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just put the bootstrap `p-0` [class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/#notation)

```
<div class="col-2 p-0">
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get red area cover the the pink area?
For that you have to override the style of your css framework for `col-2'

```
.override-class
{
padding-right: 0px!important;
padding-left: 0px!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to change it for all class named `col-2`, try this inline CSS

```
<div class="col-2" style="background-color:#f0f; padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px;">
```

Else you can try this one

```
.col-2{
  padding-right: 0px !important;
  padding-left: 0px !important;
}
```

---

```css
.col-2{
  padding-right: 0px !important;
  padding-left: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2" style="background-color:#f0f;">
      <div class="nav flex-column" style="background-color:#f00;">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
        </li>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-10">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

***Bootstrap 4.0.0-beta*** has some utility class for margin, padding, gutter, vertical align and more... please checkout this code snippet...

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2 p-0" style="background-color:#f0f;">
      <div class="nav flex-column" style="background-color:#f00;">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
        </li>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-10">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>



</div>
```